# Try/catch and declared variables

Tags: variables, runtime-error, try-catch, filereader

I have tried moving around the location of my Try/Catch statements and I can't find a way to fit the code into both try statements without undeclaring the br or fr variables

Here is the output I get:

```
Suzanne Hilltop 75 88 94 81 91 94 83 88 100 100 84 97 100 96 88 89 96 94 74 97 98 100
Trina Waters 67 47 74 52 78 71 63 68 84 71 72 73 82 80 81 84 78 75 80 88 75 79
null
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.StringReader.<init>(StringReader.java:50)
    at java.util.Scanner.<init>(Scanner.java:702)
    at CSCE111_textProject.main(CSCE111_textProject.java:26)
```

The names and numbers are lines 2 and 4 of the file, which is 5 names with 22 assignment grades per name.

I'm extremely new to programming and I have never encountered a "run-time" error where it compiles but doesn't run still. My TA wasn't able to find out the issues either when I asked him.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;


class CSCE111_textProject {

    public static void main( String [] args) {

        try{

            FileReader Fr = new FileReader( "Students.txt" );
            BufferedReader Br = new BufferedReader( Fr);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException F) {
                System.out.println("I/O Exception");
            }
            String line = Br.readLine();
            try{
            while (line != null) {
                line = Br.readLine();
                System.out.println( line );


                    Scanner parser = new Scanner( line);
                    String firstname = parser.next();
                    String lastname = parser.next();
                    double test1 = parser.nextDouble();
                    double test2 = parser.nextDouble();
                    double test3 = parser.nextDouble();
                    double test4 = parser.nextDouble();
                    double quiz1 = parser.nextDouble();
                    double quiz2 = parser.nextDouble();
                    double quiz3 = parser.nextDouble();
                    double quiz4 = parser.nextDouble();
                    double quiz5 = parser.nextDouble();
                    double quiz6 = parser.nextDouble();
                    double quiz7 = parser.nextDouble();
                    double quiz8 = parser.nextDouble();
                    double hw1 = parser.nextDouble();
                    double hw2 = parser.nextDouble();
                    double hw3 = parser.nextDouble();
                    double hw4 = parser.nextDouble();
                    double hw5 = parser.nextDouble();
                    double hw6 = parser.nextDouble();
                    double hw7 = parser.nextDouble();
                    double hw8 = parser.nextDouble();
                    double hw9 = parser.nextDouble();
                    double hw10 = parser.nextDouble();
                    line = Br.readLine();

                    double testaverage = ((test1 * test2 * test3 * test4)/4);
                    double quizaverage = ((quiz1 * quiz2 * quiz3 * quiz4 * quiz5 * quiz6 * quiz7 * quiz8)/8);
                    double hwaverage = ((hw1 * hw2 * hw3 * hw4 * hw5 * hw6 * hw7 * hw8 * hw9 * hw10)/10);

                    double totalaverage = ((testaverage * .6)+(quizaverage * .25)+(hwaverage * .15));


                    FileWriter fw = new FileWriter( "Average.txt");
                    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter( fw );

                    String Line1 = (firstname + lastname + totalaverage);
                    bw.write(Line1);

                    bw.newLine();
                    String Line2 = (firstname + lastname + totalaverage);   
                    bw.write(Line2);

                    bw.newLine();
                    String Line3 = (firstname + lastname + totalaverage);
                    bw.write(Line3);

                    bw.newLine();
                    String Line4 = (firstname + lastname + totalaverage);
                    bw.write(Line4);

                    bw.newLine();
                    String Line5 = (firstname + lastname + totalaverage);
                    bw.write(Line5);
            } 
            } catch (IOException I ) {
                System.out.println("I/O Exception");

            }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Comment on your code, unrelated to your question... arrays are your friend! Consider using a single array to replace test1-test4, another array for quiz1-quiz8, etc.

Comment: I have never used arrays before. I'll look into how to do them if I get this code working and have time to spare though

Answer (score 0):

Doesn't look like your runtime error is due to your try/catch blocks.

Looks like you have a null pointer exception because your looping logic as you read the file is a bit off. I've added some inline comments to illustrate.

```
while (line != null) {
    // AKIRA: at this point, line != null, otherwise we wouldn't have entered the loop
    line = Br.readLine();
    // AKIRA: read off the next chunk from the file and assigned that to the var line, so it's got a new value
    System.out.println(line);
    /// AKIRA: what's the last thing that gets printed in your output before the exception is thrown?
    Scanner parser = new Scanner( line);
```

Hopefully this makes it clearer. You need to carefully think about the sequencing of calls within your loop. Once you enter the top of the loop, you are committed to run through the entire loop.